# Android: How to fetch the key value of push()

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a feedback app where the customer has to submit a rating (1-5) and that data pushes onto Firebase realtime database. The database in Firebase which looks like this -

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "-MCHoOShwgxPE3u2drjz" : {
      "Arpit Mundra" : {
        "name" : "Arpit Mundra",
        "rating" : 5
      }
    },
    "-MCHqbF4UvX02OYJNuPv" : {
      "Ankit Mundra" : {
        "name" : "Ankit Mundra",
        "rating" : 5
      }
    },
    "-MCHr-q_amx1vBJkyq2S" : {
      "Harsh Chauhan" : {
        "name" : "Harsh Chauhan",
        "rating" : 5
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to calculated the average of the `rating` of all the users which falls under user which again falls under the push() id. My question is how do I fetch the unique push() id to extract the rating value from it?

Here is the code -

```
package com.example.feedback;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.StringRes;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class Score extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView avgScore;
    DatabaseReference dbRef;
    String mGroupID = dbRef.child("Users").push().getKey();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //will hide the title
        getSupportActionBar().hide(); // hide the title bar
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); //enable full screen
        setContentView(R.layout.score);
        avgScore = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(mGroupID);

        scoreRealTime();
    }

    public void scoreRealTime() {
        dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                double total = 0;
                for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    double values = Double.parseDouble(ds.child("rating").getValue().toString());
                    total = total + values;
                }
                double average = (double) total / snapshot.getChildrenCount();
                avgScore.setText(String.format("%.2f", average));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It is throwing a NullPointerException error at String `mGroupID = dbRef.child("Users").push().getKey();` line.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just get the user snapshot and then get the rating fro the object sir.`

```
 databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

         databaseReference .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override

    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

        double total = 0;

        for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()){

      UserHelper helper = ds.getValue(UserHelper.class);

            double values =
         Double.parseDouble(helper.rating);

            total = total + values;

        }

        double average = (double) total / snapshot.getChildrenCount();

            avgScore.setText(String.format("%.2f", average));

         }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code here is trying to use dbRef before it is assigned a value:

```
DatabaseReference dbRef;
String mGroupID = dbRef.child("Users").push().getKey();
```

`dbRef` is initially null.  It doesn't get a value until later when `onCreate` is called.  What you'll have to do is wait until dbRef has a value before you call methods on it.  Don't assign `mGroupID` immediately, and instead move the assignment after `dbRef` has a value.

```
dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
mGroupID = dbRef.push().getKey();
```

Comment: I tried this solution too but it throws an error saying "Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()". It's probably because mGroupID is null when being passed in dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(mGroupID);

Comment: Then, for the exact same reason, you're going to have to figure out what mGroupId is before you use it.  You can't have them both depend on each other.  One has to come first.  I made a suggestion by editing my answer.  You will have to verify that it works for the rest of the class.

Comment: Umm now the nullpointexception is occuring at 
double values = Double.parseDouble(ds.child("rating").getValue().toString()); 
Says toString() can't be performed on a null object

Comment: If you have a new problem, please post it separately.  Stack Overflow is not a very effective debugger.